# Word VBA Userform, Getting Control Object By Name fails sometimes

Tags: vba, checkbox, ms-word, userform

I have a userform “myUserForm” with dozens of controls whose TypeName() is “CheckBox”. I just hate having dozens of _Click() routines named like “Private Sub Chk1_Click()”, so in order to manage the quantity of _Click() routines, I simplified and made them nearly identical:

```
Private Sub Chk1_Click()
  ProcessClickFor ("Chk1")
End Sub
Private Sub Chk2_A_Click()
  ProcessClickFor ("Chk2_A")
End Sub
Private Sub Chk3_Z_Click()
  ProcessClickFor ("Chk3_Z")
End Sub
```

ProcessClickFor() does most of the work.

```
Sub ProcessClickFor(anyCheckBox As String)
     Dim cbControl As Object
     Set cbControl = ControlByName(anyCheckBox)
     If cbControl.Value Then
        cbControl.Value = True
     End If
End Sub
```

Later, when I want to work with any control, I can get the Control object by name, like:

```
  Dim aControl As Object
  Set aControl = ControlByName(“Chk3”)
  MsgBox  “The control named “ & cbControl.Name & “ is “ & cbControl.Visible

Function ControlByName(sName) As Object
    Dim objectified As Object
    For Each objectified In myUserForm.Controls
        If objectified.Name = sName Then
            Set ControlByName = objectified
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next objectified
End Function
```

This works fine, *almost*, but it FAILS on the same four controls on myUserForm *every* time.

The failure “mode” is that ControlByName() seems to return successfully, but the first use of the returned control (such as my MsgBox) gives the error:

```
"Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set".
```

I verified that the spelling of the defined control names matches the names in my _Click() routines. Dozens of similarly designed CheckBox controls work perfectly.  Could it have to do with the length of the CheckBox names or the number of “_” characters in the CheckBox names? Could there be a corrupt character in a CheckBox name? Can you think of other things for me to try?

Comment: What's the error you get?  Not a fix, but your situation would be a good use case for this - http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/08/05/vba-control-arrays/

Comment: I sometimes had behavior that things got just wrong in a Form. Deleting and creating the affected controls from scratch helped me.

Comment: Tim, I will fix my description and say that the error is: "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set". 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Bruno Bieri's comment turns out to be the correct answer! I deleted the controls and re-created them with identical names, and everything started working. Astonishing, but true.